# Angular JS issues sending JSON with $ http

Tags: json, angularjs, post

I am having issue sending post json data with angular, from PHP I need to access $_POST['action']

This works

```
   $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: ajaxurl,
                data: "action=get_employer_jobs",
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).success(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.jobs = data;
            });
```

This does not work

```
   app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
            console.log('MainController Running');
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: ajaxurl,
                data: JSON.stringify({action:"get_employer_jobs"}),
                headers:  {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            }).success(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.jobs = data;
            });
        }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to process your json on the server side differently.

in PHP, I do it like this:

```
$_REQUEST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

The way Angular sends POST data as json strings, you need to take the whole request string, parse it, then you can use it. It won't automatically be in $_POST or $_REQUEST as a nice array until you do this parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I´d the same problem, it looks like PHP doesn´t fill the `$_POST` array when it´s passed by the `$http` service.

Instead of using `$_POST`, try to parse directly the `php://input`.

`php
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
var_dump($request)`

Then you can access using the object notation `$request->my_var`